# Could we define multiplication of “complex numbers” in this way?

Tags: complex-numbers, number-systems

If we define multiplication of complex numbers as follows:
$$z_1 \cdot z_2=(x_1x_2+y_1y_2, x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$$ then it can be shown that it induces a group structure $(G, \cdot)$, because it has inverse elements:
$$z^{-1}=\left(\frac{x}{x^2-y^2},\frac{y}{-x^2+y^2}\right)$$
 and the unit element appears also: $(1,0)$. It is also commutative and satisfies all other conditions (I think so). So why not define multiplication of complex numbers like this? Does this definition lead into contradiction? Of course you have no definition whatsoever for $\sqrt{-1}$, because now $i^2=1$ implies $i=1$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number

Comment: What is the inverse of $(1,1)$?

Comment: well condition is that $y^2-x^2 \neq 0$

Comment: So a whole bunch of elements are missing. Doesn't really look like the complex numbers to me...

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question; it's _wrong_ but that shouldn't be a reason to downvote here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the ring $\mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2-1)$ in disguise; the equivalence class of the polynomial $a+bt$ corresponds to the ordered pair $(a,b)$, as you can see:
$$\begin{align*}
(x_1+y_1t)(x_2+y_2t)&=x_1y_1+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)t+(x_2y_2)t^2\\\\
&\equiv (x_1y_1+x_2y_2)+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)t\mod (t^2-1).
\end{align*}$$
There's nothing "wrong" with this ring, but I think it is fair to say that it is less useful than the complex numbers.

Comment: this is accidental.

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to mean - the system you have described is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2-1)$, that's the answer to your question.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: If you mean the additive structure, then yes, they are both isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. But while $\mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2-1)$ is a useful ring, I think it is hard to top the usefulness of the complex numbers...

Comment: I mean my example was not made on purpose.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Same multiplicative structure? Why do you say that?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR it is not the same multiplication structure. This is not a even a field.

Comment: @Vishal (and others): Oh oops, I didn't notice that it's $\mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2 - 1)$, rather than $\mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2 + 1)$ which is the complex numbers. Sorry. :-)

Comment: Hello. What does $R[x]/(f(x))$ means? Heaveno.

Comment: @alvoultai: $R[x]$ is a ring. For any $f\in R[x]$, we can form the ideal $(f)$. Then $R[x]/(f)$ denotes [the quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have given a group structure to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (apart from the addition). This is not the complex numbers. The definitive property of the complex numbers is algebraic closure, which is missing here. The multiplication structure you gave does not even make it into a field.

Comment: Well I know now that "algebraic closure of the field of real numbers is the field of complex numbers". But I do not know that can you explain me how real numbers form algebraic closure of complex numbers.

Comment: Real numbers forming algebraic closure of complex numbers?

Comment: Well, can you explain how "algebraic closure of the field of real numbers is the field of complex numbers".I mean this algebraic closure is hard to grasp.

Comment: You do realize that the OP's ring is not a field, right?

Comment: This is something you can look up. The fact that complex field is algebraically closed has several proofs.

Comment: @wj32. Yes, oh! Perhaps my answer makes it look like it is a field. I will edit it.